# How to add a new Keybinding for the Parenthesis sign in Visual Code Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, parentheses

Keybinding (Keyboard Shortcuts) list prints no entries for shift + 9 binding. Are such regular keys hardcoded? Is the "(" symbol represented by any code or an action name in VSC? If yes, can the keybinding file be manually changed in keybindings.json?

The actual goal is to change position of the sign's triggering button on keyboard.

Is there an other crude alternative as changing system keyboard layout?

// as suggested, this works

```
"args": { "text": "(" }
"args": { "snippet": "(" }
```

Comment: add key bindings to whatever key you want to use command `type` to type the char(s) you want. You can load a different language keyboard in the OS even a Dvorak layout